# removeClass from div

Tags: jquery, list, backbone.js, editing, removeclass

I have this JS function:

```
 editall: function() {   
  $('#divedit').removeClass("editing editing2 saving");
  $(this.el).addClass("editing editing2 saving");
},


HTML
<script type="text/template" id="item-template">
<li class="<%= done ? 'completed' : '' %>">
<div class="view">

  <label class="edit-shopname"><%= shopname %></label>
  <label class="edit-shopadress"><%= shopadress %></label>
  <button class="all-edit"></button>
  <button class="todo-destroy"></button>
</div>
<div id="divedit">
    <input class="edit" value="<%= shopname %>">
    <input class="edit2" value="<%= shopadress %>">
    <button class="save"></button>
</div>
  </li>
</script>
```

it's not working

I m not sure if this is the best way to do this,
But my idea its to remove all the classes in this "div" (divedit) before adding again when I press my edit button on other list item.
These items came from my database and are added dynamically.
I want to start editing new item and close all the editing class added before on the other item.

Javascript complete object adapted from parse.com TODO example

```
 var ShopView = Parse.View.extend({ 

//... is a list tag.
tagName:  "li",

// Cache the template function for a single item.
template: _.template($('#item-template').html()),

// The DOM events specific to an item.
events: {       
       "click .todo-destroy"   : "clear",
   "click .all-edit"   : "editall",
    },

// The TodoView listens for changes to its model, re-rendering. Since there's
// a one-to-one correspondence between a Todo and a TodoView in this
// app, we set a direct reference on the model for convenience.


initialize: function() {
  _.bindAll(this, 'render', 'close', 'remove');
  this.model.bind('change', this.render);
  this.model.bind('destroy', this.remove);
},

// Re-render the contents of the todo item.
render: function() {
  $(this.el).html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
 this.input = this.$('.edit');
 //this.input = this.$('.edit2');
  return this;

},

// Toggle the `"done"` state of the model.
toggleDone: function() {
     this.model.toggle();
},

// Switch this view into `"editing"` mode, displaying the input field.
 editall: function() {      
$('#divedit').removeClass("editing editing2 saving");
    $(this.el).addClass("editing editing2 saving");
this.input.focus();
},
   // Close the `"editing"` mode, saving changes to the todo.
close: function() {
    //$(this.el).removeClass("editing");
    //$(this.el).removeClass("editing2");

        this.model.save({shopname: this.input.val()});
        $(this.el).removeClass("editing");};
        console.log("close2");
        /his.model.save({shopadress: this.input.val()});
        $(this.el).removeClass("editing2");};
},

// If you hit `enter`, we're through editing the item.
updateOnEnter: function(e) {
  if (e.keyCode == 13) this.close();
},

// Remove the item, destroy the model.
clear: function() {
  this.model.destroy();
}
```

});

Comment: `$("#somedivID").removeClass("editing editing2 saving");`

Comment: Is divedit a div id?  If so -  $('#divedit').removeClass("editing editing2 saving"); should work

Comment: yes diveit its a div id, but its not working. Maybe its because (this.el) its inside same div? and browser can't render this at same time, removing and adding same Class in same div?

Comment: No, it's because your code is missing two quotes and a hash...

Comment: sorry if i was not clear, i already tried $('#divedit'). its not working

Comment: What object is your function inside - can we see the code? If it's not inside an object it's declared incorrectly.

Comment: Its inside "var ShopView = Parse.View.extend({...", i trying to adapt from parse.com TODO example. I don't understand all the code.i can remove class using "$(this.el).removeClass("editing");", but only remove from the item i m editing. i want to remove class from the previous item i was editing

Comment: There is still code missing. Please show the html part that uses the .all-edit class.

Comment: Ok Dirk Lachowski, Updated my post. Not sure if is that html part you want.

Comment: I just gave up from this approach, couldn't find a way to remove Classes from my model using div id as target. Anyway, i found a way to workaround this, and its working great. Thanks all who tried to help :) Cheers